# when execute shell file in docker container, binary file error

Tags: docker

I'm trying to execute shell file that contains python script.
But, I don't know why i met the error like this
file directory structure
/home/kwstat/workplace/analysis/report_me

- home

  - kwstat

    - workplace

      - analysis

        - report_me

          - report_me.sh
          - python_file

            - python_code.py
              ...

```
$docker exec -it test /bin/bash -c "source /home/kwstat/workplace/analysis/report_me/report_me.sh"

# Error
/home/kwstat/workplace/analysis/report_me/report_me.sh: line 30: source: /usr/local/bin/python: cannot execute binary file
```

I tried several things in Dockerfile, But same error occured.

```
# 1.CMD ["/bin/bash","-l","-c"]
CMD ["/bin/bash","-l","-c"]

# 2. CMD bin/bash
CMD bin/bash
```

#########My Dockerfile#############

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

# System packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y subversion

WORKDIR /home/kwstat/workplace/analysis/report_me
COPY environments.yml /home/kwstat/workplace/analysis/report_me/environments.yml
RUN conda env create -f /home/kwstat/workplace/analysis/report_me/environments.yml

# Make RUN commands use the new environment:
SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "myenv", "/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN echo "conda activate my_env" >> ~/.profile
# Activate the environment, and make sure it's activated:
#RUN echo "Make sure flask is installed:"

COPY requirements.txt /home/kwstat/me_report_dockerfile/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /home/kwstat/me_report_dockerfile/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /home/kwstat/workplace/analysis/report_me/python_file
COPY python_file/ /home/kwstat/workplace/analysis/report_me/python_file

WORKDIR /home/kwstat/workplace/analysis/report_me/
COPY report_me.sh ./report_me.sh
RUN chmod +x report_me.sh

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

please any help ~

Comment: The error message points to a pretty specific place in the script; can you include that in your question?

Comment: the specific place was python that was installed in my docker. And the shell script was operate python file. Do you mean include shell script??

Answer (score 0):

my problem was from shell script.
Inside the shell set the coda env path
and all solved.